# Hibernate "No CurrenetSessionContext "Error

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have been trying to get a Spring / Hibernate project going, and can't seem to get it to run.  I am getting the error below.  I think I am close to getting it work, but I am obviously missing something.  Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code?  I'd love to know, because I've spent 4 days trying to get this to work, and have gotten nowhere.

This is the error I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured!
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:542)
    at cmsutil.dao.ContentComponentDAOImpl.getContentComponents(ContentComponentDAOImpl.java:37)
    at cmsutil.util.Driver.main(Driver.java:22)
```

applicationContext

```
  <context:property-placeholder location="jdbc.properties"/>

  <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.url}"
        p:username="${jdbc.username}"
        p:password="${jdbc.password}"/>

  <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
        p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
        p:configurationClass="org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration"
        p:packagesToScan="cmsutil.dao">
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">${hibernate.generate_statistics}</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
    <property name="eventListeners">
      <map>
        <entry key="merge">
          <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.IdTransferringMergeEventListener"/>
        </entry>
      </map>
    </property>

  </bean>

  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txnManager"/>

  <bean id="txnManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager"
        p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory"/>
</beans>
```

The hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <mapping resource="contentcomponent.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

DAO

```
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Transactional
@Repository("contentComponentDAO")
public class ContentComponentDAOImpl implements ContentComponentDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


    public ContentComponentDAOImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
    }


    public ContentComponentDAOImpl() {
    }

    @Override
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }


    @Override
    public List<ContentComponent> getContentComponents() throws DAOException {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<ContentComponent> documents;

        Query query = session.getNamedQuery("ContentComponent.findAllContentComponents");
        documents = query.list();
        return documents;
    }
```

And finally, the testing driver:

```
package cmsutil.util;

import cmsutil.dao.ContentComponentDAOImpl;
import cmsutil.exceptions.DAOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws DAOException {
        AbstractApplicationContext factory = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        ContentComponentDAOImpl c = new ContentComponentDAOImpl();
        c.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
        List l = c.getContentComponents();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dao is not being managed by spring, you have just manually created an instance of dao.  Therefore nothing will be autowired.

You have two options - allow hibernate session to be injected into dao (passed in as parameter in constructor).  Or call your beans from the loaded app context.

If it is for the puposes of unit testing, you could pass in a mock object.

Answer (score 0):

Your test driver makes no sense. If you want to make sure that Spring application context works, use beans obtained from the context:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws DAOException {
    AbstractApplicationContext factory = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");        
    ContentComponentDAO c = factory.getBean(ContentComponentDAO.class);
    List l = c.getContentComponents();  
}
```

Also you don't need `hibernate.cfg.xml`, since Hibernate is configured in Spring application context in your case.

Comment: I think I am getting closer, but now I get

    NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

ContentComponentDAOImpl c = factory.getBean(ContentComponentDAOImpl.class);
c.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

Comment: @BusterBunker: As I can see from the use of `@Repository` you expected `ContentComponentDAOImpl` to be autodetected as a bean. If so, you need to enable autodetection with [`<context:component-scan>`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-scanning-autodetection).